# Keeping a part of webpage that has too many divs, fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage which has too many divs in it.I want to keep a portion of webpage page fixed even when It is scrolling down

**The Problem**

I tried it with many combinations.But the problem is due to too many divs I am not able to "cut" a section of webpage with a div to which I can assign class having `position:fixed`.Any help will be really appreciated

My actual HTML code (I am using django so there are many django/jinja variables in it ignore them)

```
{% block content %}

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">My Webpage</h4>
                <p class="card-description" style="color:black;">
                  Zone for Gasoline:A, Year :2018
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="btn-group btn-block mb-4" aria-label="Brand placement algorithm steps">
                    <div class="col md-4">
                    <a href="/app/step-1/"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary"> Step 1 </button> </a>
                    </div>

                <div class="col md-4">
                    <a href="/app/step-2/"> <button type="button"  class="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary" > Step 2  </button> </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col md-4">
                    <a href="/app/step-3/"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"> Step 3 </button></a>
                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="capture-this">
                    <div class="gridster">
                        <table border = "1" class=".table-responsive">
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="4"  style="background-color:#05345c;">Zone 1</th>
                                <th colspan="4"  style="background-color:#05345c;">Zone 2</th>
                                <th colspan="4"  style="background-color:#05345c;">Zone 3</th>
                                {% ifequal request.session.step 4 %}    
                                <th colspan="4"  style="background-color:#05345c;">Period 4</th>
                                {% endifequal %}
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T1</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T2</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T3</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T4</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T1</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T2</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T3</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T4</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T1</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T2</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T3</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T4</td>
                                {% ifequal request.session.step 4 %}    
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T1</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T2</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T3</td>
                                <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T4</td>
                                {% endifequal %}
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    <!---I want webpage till here to remain fixed -->
                        <ul>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>



                {% block content_controls %}
                {% endblock %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**What I want**

I basically want webpage till `</table>` tag to remain fixed.I am using Gridster which has widgets in the form of `<li>` elements so those will come under the `<ul>`.

There will be too many such `<li>` elements so when user scrolls down the `<table>` and above content should be fixed

[A rough Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxtsaxnx/)(The fiddle is to get idea how the webpage looks like)
In fiddle I am expecting that till table row having value T1,T2, T3, T4 .... the webpage should remain fix

Comment: In your fiddle first 5 divs do not have a closing tag.
Is that the same in production code?Can you update it adding closing tag?

Comment: Can you please look over this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186183/scrolling-child-div-within-a-parent-div I have made some modification