# Scrolling child div within a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Some background**

I am using [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) widgets for webpage.These widgets are displayed below an HTML table.The table helps in identifying some information for each widget.The widgets are html `<li>` elements placed in `<ul>`.

The widgets are generated dynamically from a json.(So they are not fixed in number)

**My desired output**

Since the widgets are dynamically generated there can be too many widgets.When this happens the webpage becomes too big and user cant see the HTML table.

So what I want is that the part in which widgets are there should scroll, the HTML table being fixed at its position

Due to which even when user wants to see the widgets which are at bottom he can see the HTML table with it

**What I have tried so far**

I made a `<div>` to the part in which widgets are there and gave the property `overflow:scroll` to them.But even then its not working in the way I am expecting

My HTML

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">My Webpage</h4>
           <p class="card-description" style="color:black;">
                      Zone for Gasoline:A, Year :2018
            </p>
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="btn-group btn-block mb-4" aria-label="steps">
                     <div class="col md-4">
                        <a href="/app/step-1/"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary"> Step 1 </button> </a>
                         </div>
                <div class="col md-4">
                        <a href="/app/step-2/"> <button type="button"  class="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary" > Step 2  </button> </a>
                      </div>
                 <div class="col md-4">
                        <a href="/app/step-3/"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"> Step 3 </button></a>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>


  <table border = "1" class=".table-responsive">
     <tr>
        <th colspan="4"  style="background-color:#eedd82;">Zone 1</th>
        <th colspan="4"  style="background-color:#eedd82;">Zone 2</th>
        <th colspan="4"  style="background-color:#eedd82;">>Zone 3</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T1</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T2</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T3</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T4</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T1</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T2</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T3</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T4</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T1</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T2</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T3</td>
        <td width="400" align="center" style="background-color:#0085ca">T4</td>
     </tr>
 </table>

 <!--Gridster widgets will appear here below table-->
 <div class="gridster father">
      <ul class="child">

      </ul>
</div>
```

I am sorry for so big HTML code.In HTML you can see that below `<table>` I have given a class `father` to the `<div>` and `child` to `<ul>` element.

For both of them I tried the following CSS(individually and in combined way)

```
.father{
    overflow:scroll;
  }

.child{
    overflow:scroll;
  }
```

But I was not giving the "scrolling" effect which I wanted

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mr29uew4/) representing the same

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you wish to apply scrolling to enable responsive behaviour on smaller displays such a s mobile phone, overflow scroll should be applied to a parent of the table to enable scrolling like so

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <ul class="child">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

For a better responsive experience we probably only want this scrolling to be left to right (y-axis) and not top to bottom (x-axis) we need to set this as well and so therefore need to adjust our CSS accordingly.

```
.parent {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

In your example it looks like the father and child classes are being applied to the grid build as an unordered list (`<ul>`) with the little car icons in. This `<ul>` is defining the height and with of the the parent, so therefore in a large enough window the table would not be expected to scroll. If you compress the window however the parent element only expands to the width of the window which is expected behaviour of a div. At this point the child element does scroll.

If you wish to apply this same behaviour to the `.table-responsive` element you need to apply the same principle. Wrap the table in a parent and apply the overflow accordingly. You do not want to put `overflow-scroll` on the table itself, but you may wish to give the table a min-width or apply a fixed width such as `width: 300px;`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <table class="table-responsive">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.table-responsive {
    your styles
}
```

If you need to fix the dimensions of the parent so that the element does not define the size of the window you could do something like so with your CSS

```
.parent {
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: 400px;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
.table-responsive {
    your styles
}
```

In this case your width will ideally be 400px wide, but never exceed the viewport width and never be more that 400px high, but never exceed the viewport height.
If you want to get even cleverer with your height you could use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) for you max height so the that window never exceeds a specific height taking into consideration other elements on the page.

Comment: It is not necessarily with mobile phone.It can be also on desktop.My main aim is that however many widgets are there.The "box" or "container" in which they are should remain of fixed size.My webpage should not expand depending on widgets

Comment: @NewBie You would be able to fix the size of the parent container by defining the height and width. The child element would scroll if it exceeds these dimension whether that be width ways or by height.

Answer (score -2):

Responsive Tables are not written like that. It's like this :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```